# download a zip file via http with npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

There is a zip file at some http:// | https:// location.

In this case it's a zip of assets, in particular a font, so it's not a js package and has no git repository or other kind of repository.

With bower one could just reference the location and it would download and extract the zip file.

How can I achieve this with npm? Preferably without hacks, because my `postinstall` script already does a bunch of stuff.

Comment: The fact that it is a zip file doesn't impact the download process, you could just use `fetch` for that. For the unzipping, the first hit Google gave me seems to do the trick => [node-unzip-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-unzip-2)

Comment: what do you mean with `fetch`?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question, I thought you wanted to do this in JS under NPM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in file `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node download.js && <whatever you had here before>"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "download-file": "0.1.5"
  }
```

And then add this in file `download.js` next to file `package.json`:

```
var download = require('download-file')
const url = "https://YourFileLocation";
const options = {directory: "YourDirName", filename: "YourFileName"};
console.log("Installing " + options.directory + "/" + options.filename);
download(url, options, function(error) {if (error) throw error;});
```

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/download-file

Comment: `postinstall` takes bash commands and if anything it should be in `devDependencies`

Comment: @altu: I removed the part where I explain how to do the post install part, because I figured you had the same setup as my own. Let me reinstate that part into the answer. Second, it can be both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

Comment: I'll accept it although I went a different route and put the zip file contents on a private git repo and then used git+ssh:// to add the package to dependencies. (Don't forget to add a package.json file). Regarding devDependencies, the scope is just for fetching a zip and unpacking. Yes both work but contextual dependencies are good practice because reasons.